Is a married rape victim to be put to death according to Deuteronomy 22:22?
I asked this on the Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange, but I would also appreciate your input greatly.
Deuteronomy 22:22 states:

If a man is found lying with the wife of another man, both of them shall die, the man who lay with the woman, and the woman. So you shall purge the evil from Israel. (Deuteronomy 22:22, ESV)

Does that mean, then, that Deuteronomy 22:22 implies that a married rape victim should be killed? I think that this question is relevant because there isn't anywhere else in the Torah that I know of that deals with the rape of a married woman.
I have heard people try to use Deuteronomy 22:25 as proof that the rapist of both a married or an unmarried victim alike should be killed (and the woman not), but is this a valid interpretation? Deuteronomy 22:25 refers to a betrothed woman specifically. But, if it isn't valid, where can we find out what the punishment is for a man who rapes a married woman, and for a man who rapes an unmarried, unbetrothed, woman? And what should be done to her? I know some people will use Deuteronomy 22:28-29 in the case of the unbetrothed woman, but there is debate on whether this passage actually refers to rape or not.
Is there anywhere else in the Tanakh that implies that the married woman is not considered to be an adulteress?
What were the interpretations of this? Do we know how it was applied?

A rape victim is not put to death, no. She is not even required to divorce her husband, unless he's a Cohen.

Deuteronomy 22:25 refers to a betrothed woman specifically. No. The Talmud consider that to be the source for the general principle that people are not punished for circumstances beyond their control. When it comes to adultery, the main difference between a married and "betrothed" woman is with respect to the form of punishment, but both are forbidden to other men and neither are liable for being raped.

There is no tape victim here mentioned and why would you assume so?

@Dude The word used for "lying with" in this verse is the same word that is used a few verses later in the context of rape.

(Usual disclosure -- Jews do not carry out the death penalty today!)
Goodness no. That was talking about if she cheated of her own free will. Read it in context of the next few verses. (Please use a Jewish translation here. Have a look at Sefaria; though honestly, any translation is going to make this clear, if you look forward a few verses and think this through a bit.)
Rape is covered a few verses later, very, very clearly. You wouldn't blame a murder victim, so why blame a rape victim?

But if in the field the man encounters the married girl, and the man holds her and had intercourse with her; then he shall die—only the man who had intercourse with her. But to the girl you will not do a thing, the girl has no death liability; for, just as if a man rises up against his peer and murders him, so is this matter. For he encountered her in the field; the married girl screamed, but there was no one to rescue her.

If she cheated of her own free will, there are two slightly different cases. If she was still a virgin, but married (they used to do "betrothal" a few months before moving in together), then it's especially outrageous for her to have cheated, so the punishment is stoning:

If there will be a virgin girl married to a man, and a man encounters her in the city and has intercourse with her, You are to take them both out to the court of that city and stone them with stones to death, the girl for the fact that she did not scream in the city and the man for the fact that he oppressed the wife of his peer; and you will eliminate the evil within you.

"She didn't scream out", i.e. she did it willingly.
Verse 22 is a tangent off of that; if she cheated of her own free will but was had already moved in with her husband, it's still the death penalty, but the verse doesn't specify stoning. (The Talmud says it's strangulation instead, which was considered less severe than stoning.)

If a man is found having intercourse with a woman who is the wife of a man, even both of them shall die—the man who had intercourse with the woman and the woman—and you will eliminate the evil from Yisroel.

So the overall flow of the verses would then read:



She cheated during full marriage -- strangulation for both of them.


23--24. She cheated during betrothal -- stoning for both of them.
25--27. She was raped? Kill the rapist, don't punish her at all.

Note that the last case gets the most verses; it's trying to really drive home that point that we do not blame rape victims!
(Yes, sometimes you have to scan the text forwards and backwards a bit to understand it properly.)
If the Torah says don't blame a rape victim, just as you wouldn't blame a murder victim and gives that explicit reasoning, it would boggle the mind to claim that somehow if she was cohabitating with her husband that it would somehow be worse than if she was betrothed. (In fact, we can apply a fortiori logic: cheating during betrothal is considered worse than cheating during normal marriage. So if we don't blame her for being raped during betrothal, we certainly don't blame her for being raped during normal marriage.)
This is how the Talmud and subsequent halachic codes read it, very, very clearly.

Maybe I'm being nitpicky, but the term "cheated" makes it sound like a personal squabble, as opposed to the severe sin of adultery. It also implies a husband and wife would be comparably liable for extramarital relations, which isn't the case (setting aside the marital status of the third party).

@shmosel I'm using contemporary vernacular, as a quick shorthand to contrast with "rape", for the purposes of the OP here who is clearly not well-versed in halacha.  (In hachi nami.)

Thank you for your answer. What is interesting to me is that these translations render the phrase "married girl" instead of "betrothed girl". Can the word also refer to a woman who is in a marriage that has been consummated, or am I misunderstanding?

@Tom yeah sorry, this particular translation didn't make that distinction; many other Jewish translations do. "Betrothal" is a binding marriage, but they used to wait a year before moving in and consummating. Verse 22, consummated, uses  Be'ulat baal, lit. "husbanded by a husband." 23, 25, 27 all use me'orasa, "betrothed.". (And 28 uses "not me'orasa", i.e. single.) You'll see a similar distinction in Numbers 30:7 -- "if she shall be to a man", vs. Numbers 30:11 -- "if she was in her husband's home." (7 is just betrothed, 11 is moved-in.)

Have a look at Sefaria, you'll be able to compare a few different Jewish translations. The challenge is always how to balance English readability with the precision of the Hebrew original.

I think it is worth pointing out when non-Jews ask questions like this that the Bible is only the basis of Jewish Law, not the whole thing, so the actual final law is likely to be far more nuanced, especially in cases such as this.  eg. I suspect that if there was any suspicion that she didn't cry out even in the city because he was in the position to kill her, or modern considerations such as lots of background noise or soundproofing then I would imagine that would be treated as rape, not as consensual on her part
